# Best practice for having the result of a same query in all routes

Tags: phoenix-framework

I would like to be able to pass data for a destak popup I have that can be shown on every route/page of my application. The data is on the database and thus I use a query to get it and pass it in a controller to a specific page:

```
def admin(conn, _params, locale) do
    destaks = Data.listAll(query)
    render(conn, "admin.html", destaks: destaks)
  end
```

What's the best way of have it available for all pages, while making sure that when I update that data in the database it is reflected automatically on all pages?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call a function in every one of your controller functions?

Comment: @Tyler Yes. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `Plug` function for this. Here is an example:

1) **Define your plug function** somewhere (for my example I put this right into `router.ex`). The first argument is the connection that we will be adding our data to, and we don't need the second argument in this case:

```
def database_thing(conn, _) do
  # This is where you get things from the database
  data_from_a_query = ["these", "will", "be", "from", "your", "query"]
  Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :values_from_database, data_from_a_query)
end
```

2) **Add plug function to a pipeline** in `router.ex`, you can add it to an existing pipeline or create a new one:

```
# Example of adding to an existing pipeline
pipeline :browser do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  plug :protect_from_forgery
  plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  plug :database_thing # add it
end

# Example of creating a new pipeline
pipeline :everytime do
  plug :database_thing
end
```

3) **Make sure that your pipeline is in your scope**.  If you added it to an existing pipeline you shouldn't have to do much.  If you created a new pipeline then you have to add it to the scope in `router.ex`:

```
scope "/", MyPhoenixApp do
  pipe_through [:browser, :everytime]

  resources "/users", UserController
end
```

4) **Access the value in the controller**.  If you look at step one, you can see that we are assigning the data with the key `:values_from_database`.  To access that data, you would do the following in your controller functions:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  IO.inspect(conn.assigns.values_from_database)
  # ...
end
```

5) **Access the value in the template**.  The `conn` is passed through the controller functions to the templates, so depending on what you are trying you may not need to access the value in the controller functions at all, and just use it directly in the template:

```
<%= @conn.assigns.values_from_database %>
```